# upgrading tfs 2008 sp1 to use sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, tfs

I have an instance of tfs 2008 supported by sql server 2005. I want to change the sql server machine by doing a restore based move. I also want to change the version of sql server to 2008.

I know that i can restore backups from sql 2005 to sql 2008, IN GENERAL, but I don't know if this is a thing that is OK for tfs databases.

I also know that sql server 2008 is supported by tfs 2008, but in this case when I have done an upgrade I am assuming that I should change the database compatibility mode to be "2008".

So, any advice on doing a sql server upgrade for TFS 2008?

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: possibly, that might make sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup databases and report server key
2. Start downtime
3. Upgrade SQL2005 to SQL2008; AT will stop working at this step
4. Apply VS SP1
5. Apply TFS SP1; AT will work again
6. Apply SQL2008 SP1
7. Verify full functionality
8. End downtime